# SQL does not recognize tablename from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I write the `tablename` after 'FROM' the query works. If I use the result of a select statement the query does not resolve. Is there a workaround?

I have tried resolving the `tablename` as an output from a stored procedure but I cannot seem to use exec in a stored procedure or function without receiving an error

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EDOFA_TABLE]
(
@DTCODE nvarchar(max) = null
,@DTAMPO nvarchar(max) = null
,@DTNDOS float = null
,@DTTFAC nvarchar(max) = null
,@DTCDEB nvarchar(max) = null
,@DTNDEB float = null
,@DTDAPP float = null
)
AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO EDOFA (DTCODE
      ,DTAMPO
      ,DTNDOS
      ,DTTFAC
      ,DTCDEB
      ,DTNDEB
      ,DTDAPP)
SELECT DTCODE
      ,DTAMPO
      ,DTNDOS
      ,DTTFAC
      ,DTCDEB
      ,DTNDEB
      ,DTDAPP
FROM (SELECT max(name) FROM sys.tables WHERE name like 'EDOFA%')
WHERE DTCODE = @DTCODE
      OR DTAMPO = @DTAMPO
      OR DTNDOS = @DTNDOS
      OR DTTFAC = @DTTFAC
      OR DTCDEB = @DTCDEB
      OR DTNDEB = @DTNDEB
      OR DTDAPP = @DTDAPP
END
```

Incorrect syntax near keyword where

Comment: That isn't how SQL works. You can't replace an object with an expression, variable name, etc. It has to be a ltieral; you need to use **parametrised** dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Hitokiri, you should give a name to `max(name)` field like this: `max(name) as 'MaxName'` and then set an alias name for `FROM (SELECT max(name) FROM sys.tables WHERE name like 'EDOFA%')` like this : `FROM (SELECT max(name) FROM sys.tables WHERE name like 'EDOFA%') table1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in my comment *"That isn't how SQL works. You can't replace an object with an expression, variable name, etc. It has to be a ltieral; you need to use **parametrised** dynamic SQL."*. I *believe* this does what you're after.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EDOFA_TABLE] (@DTCODE nvarchar(MAX) = NULL,
                                     @DTAMPO nvarchar(MAX) = NULL,
                                     @DTNDOS float = NULL,
                                     @DTTFAC nvarchar(MAX) = NULL,
                                     @DTCDEB nvarchar(MAX) = NULL,
                                     @DTNDEB float = NULL,
                                     @DTDAPP float = NULL)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO dbo.EDOFA (DTCODE,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'                       DTAMPO,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'                       DTNDOS,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'                       DTTFAC,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'                       DTCDEB,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'                       DTNDEB,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'                       DTDAPP)' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'SELECT DTCODE,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'       DTAMPO,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'       DTNDOS,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'       DTTFAC,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'       DTCDEB,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'       DTNDEB,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'       DTDAPP' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME((SELECT MAX([name]) FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE 'EDOFA%')) + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'WHERE DTCODE = @DTCODE' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'   OR DTAMPO = @DTAMPO' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'   OR DTNDOS = @DTNDOS' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'   OR DTTFAC = @DTTFAC' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'   OR DTCDEB = @DTCDEB' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'   OR DTNDEB = @DTNDEB' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'   OR DTDAPP = @DTDAPP;';

    DECLARE @Params nvarchar(MAX) = N'@DTCODE nvarchar(MAX),' +
                                    N'@DTAMPO nvarchar(MAX),' +
                                    N'@DTNDOS float,' +
                                    N'@DTTFAC nvarchar(MAX),' +
                                    N'@DTCDEB nvarchar(MAX),' +
                                    N'@DTNDEB float,' +
                                    N'@DTDAPP float';

    --PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @Params, @DTCODE, @DTAMPO, @DTNDOS, @DTTFAC, @DTCDEB, @DTNDEB, @DTDAPP;

END;
```

I build a dynamic statement, and put that into `@SQL`; along with ensuring I **properly** quote the dynamic object name, using `QUOTENAME`. Then I build the parameters and pass them all to the dynamic statement us `sp_executesql`.

If you get stuck, uncomment your best friend (and comment out the `EXEC`) and debug the printed SQL.

Comment: That is some beautifully formatted dynamic SQL, @Larnu. +1

Comment: This looks like complicated for a noob as myself but it completed when i executed it. However no data is loaded to my EDOFA table. Do u have time to run this through with me Best Friend! For good old sake :p

Comment: If no data was inserted, that implies there was no data in whatever `MAX([name])` returned, @Hitokiri . Check what yiour best firnd says

Comment: @Hitokiri, this link is worth bookmarking. I refer to it often. The author really knows his stuff. :) [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql). It has an explanation of everything in the posted answer. Coincidentally, I'm sure.

Comment: @Larnu i have checked my best friend and the only thing it does is say "commands completed succesfully" The table had an error so i remade it without errors but still no content and the table reffered to in MAX(tablename) is filled with data... I have only selected few columns and not all from source as destination. Could that be a problem? The design of the destinationtable is the same as the  designsourcetable

Comment: If that's all it says then the subquery is returning `NULL`; Clearly you have no tables with the name like `'EDOFA%'` in your database.

Comment: @Larnu EDOFA
EDOFA01118
EDOFA01218
EDOFA21118
EDOFA21218
EDOFA31118
EDOFA31218
EDOFA41118
EDOFA41218 Every quarter a new tables is added and thats why i always want the last added table from the edofa series... Hence (SELECT MAX([name]) FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE 'EDOFA%')

Comment: This does indeed work. See this [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ded1544475eecc6fd62be6d83ee5be9d). Note when no tables exist, it fails, (returns no SQL) but otherwise is fine. If the `PRINT` isn't returning a statement, the subquery found no tables; that much is clear.

Comment: @Larnu Dear Larnu, i managed to filter out everything and i printed just the 'from' u managed to provide me and did a select * statement using the FROM u provided. The result was " SELECT * FROM FROM dbo.[EDOFA_TEMP]
" It is perfectly correct but why does it not perform the stuff it prints cause i should c values...

Comment: That sentence makes no sense, @Hitokiri. If what you i've provided above isn't working, **and** the `PRINT` isn't returning anything then, like I said, you have no tables in the connected database with a name like `'EDOFA%'`; I can say that with complete certainty. Looks like you need to provide more details so that we can **replicate** the problem; as (like i said before) the above works.

Comment: @Larnu It worked Larnu Sensei. I found there were two FROM expressions in the same string. Thats why it gave no error ... I would like to thank u a lot!! What is a next step to become a better sql developer? Can i promote or like u somewhere?

Comment: Simply upvoting and/or accepted the answer as the solution is all you need to do here, @Hitokiri . If you appreciate the article I wrote that Eric linked, above you can rate that if you wish as well to show appreciation on SSC, but the upvotes/accept is all you need to do here is you want to show thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your from clause returns a scalar, and doesn't name it.  Also the subquery in the from clause needs an alias.  That's causing the error you get.

Once you add an alias, you'll get other errors. e.g. `DTAMPO` is not a column returned by the FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically include identifiers in SQL, but you can include constant values.  To do so, use `sp_executesql` like this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = '
    INSERT INTO EDOFA (DTCODE, DTAMPO, DTNDOS, DTTFAC, DTCDEB, DTNDEB, DTDAPP)
    SELECT DTCODE, DTAMPO, DTNDOS, DTTFAC, DTCDEB, DTNDEB, DTDAPP
    FROM [table]
    WHERE DTCODE = @DTCODE OR
          DTAMPO = @DTAMPO OR
          DTNDOS = @DTNDOS OR
          DTTFAC = @DTTFAC OR
          DTCDEB = @DTCDEB OR
          DTNDEB = @DTNDEB OR
          DTDAPP = @DTDAPP';

    -- Replace the table name because, alas, we cannot parameterize that
    SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL,
                      '[table]',
                       (SELECT max(name) FROM sys.tables WHERE name like 'EDOFA%')
                      );

    -- Pass everything else as parameters
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
                       N'
@DTCODE nvarchar(max),
@DTAMPO nvarchar(max),
@DTNDOS float,
@DTTFAC nvarchar(max),
@DTCDEB nvarchar(max),
@DTNDEB float,
@DTDAPP float',
                      @DTCODE=@DTCODE, @DTAMPO=@DTAMPO, @DTNDOS=@DTNDOS, @DTTFAC=@DTTFAC,
                      @DTCDEB=@DTCDEB, @DTNDEB=@DTNDEB, @DTDAPP=@DTDAPP;
END;
```

The code may be a bit more cumbersome to write, but using parameters is definitely a best practice when passing values into SQL queries.